# Trying to make a filter to retrieve data from related models

Tags: cakephp, model, filter

I have a `Post` model which `hasMany` `PostField`
every post can have several fields stored in the `post_fields` table..

`post_fields` has this structure: `(id, post_id, name, value)`

`posts` table has some common fields for all posts, but any additional fields should be stored in `post_fields` table..

I created a search form that is used to filter the posts

when specifying filters for the fields in the `posts` table, it works fine..
but I want to make the filter to work even on the other fields found in `post_fields` ..

I can retrieve the posts first then filter them manually, but i want something more efficient !

**EXAMPLE**: let's suppose that posts are describing some products..

```
post (id, title, created, price)
post_fields (id, post_id, name, value)
```

in this case, all posts have `title`, `created` and `price`..
but if a post (id=3) wants to have a `weight` field, we should do that by creating a record in `post_fields`, the record should be :

```
{ id: .. , post_id: 3, name: weight, value: .. }
```

it's easy now to filter posts according to `price` (e.g. price between `min` & `max`)..
but, what if i want to filter posts according to `weight` ??
e.g. i want all posts that have `weight` greater than 10 !!

I would like to achieve this preferably in one query, using joins maybe or subqueries ..
I don't know how to do that in cakePHP, so if any one has an idea, plz HELP !!

even if someone just has an idea but doesn't have details, that could help ...

thanx in advance !

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to search against the children of a hasMany relationship.  You will need to run your query against the PostFields model. ie: `$this->PostField->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('PostField.name' => 'weight', 'PostField.value' > 10)));`

If you want to do a query against both the PostField and Post models at the same time (ie: price < $1.00 and weight > 10, you will need to do a custom query, as CakePHP has no built-in solution for doing so TMK.  Should look something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT ... FROM posts as Post, post_fields as PostField WHERE PostField.name = 'weight' AND PostField.value > 10 AND POST.price < 1.0 AND PostField.post_id = Post.id;"
$posts = $this->Post->query($query);
```

**EDIT:**
I would do this.  You're not going to get away with doing a single call, but this is still a clean solution.

```
$postIds = null;
if(/*we need to run query against PostFields*/) {
    $conditions = array(
        'OR' => array(
            array(
                'AND' => array(
                    'PostField.name' => 'weight',
                    'PostField.value' > 10
                )
            ),
            array(
                'AND' => array(
                    'PostField.name' => 'height',
                    'PostField.value' < 10
                )
            )
        )
    );
    $fields = array('PostField.id', 'PostField.post_id');
    $postIds = $this->Post->PostField->find('list', array('conditions'=>$conditions, 'fields'=>$fields));
}
$conditions = array('Post.price' < 1.0);
if($postIds) {
    $conditions['Post.id'] = $postIds;
}
$posts = $this->Post->find('all', array('conditions'=>$conditions));
```

Comment: Using custom queries was my B plan..  but I don't prefer to use raw SQL, so I used CakePHP's sub-queries: [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions) ..

Comment: but I'm still looking if there is any way to do that in CakePHP !!

Comment: your solution is really clean and cake-like... but there is still one problem!! what if i have one extra field to filter, let's say `height` which will be in `post_fields` table !!  how can you do that in your solution ?
i already developed a solution using one `find` call... and it's working perfectly !!

Comment: I've updated the conditions above to use nested AND/OR indexes.  Code is not tested, but should get you in the right direction.

Comment: this is still not correct!!  suppose we want all posts that have a weight > 10 `and` a height > 10.. with your solution, if a post satisfies only one of these conditions but not the other, it will be accepted !! 
btw, i'm not saying that i'm trying to make it in one call.. i'm saying that i already did it !! and it's working perfectly now ...

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/474/Containable) behavior for your models. This way, you can filter the returned columns as you like. (I think this is the type of filtering you want to do)

Comment: I just finished reading about `Containable` according to your suggestion, but it's not what i'm looking for..  

I'll give an example soon to make it clearer..